# Exception in TOpenDialog when closing program

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, topendialog

When I use `TOpenDialog`, after closing the program, there is an exception in the `Vcl.Forms` module.

Program I'm using:

```cpp
std::auto_ptr<TOpenDialog> OpenDialog (new TOpenDialog(this));
if ( OpenDialog->Execute() ){}
```

Exception: 'access violation at 0x008133a4: read of address 0x000000c4'

Highlighted is line: **if not FHandleCreated then**

```pascal
function TApplication.GetDialogHandle: HWND;
begin
  if not FHandleCreated then
    Result := SendMessage(Handle, CM_DIALOGHANDLE, 1, 0)
  else
    Result := FDialogHandle;
end;
```

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using? The AV is saying a NULL pointer is being accessed.  What you describe suggests the `TApplication` object itself is being accessed after it is destroyed.  That has nothing to do with the C++ code you have shown, since the `TOpenDialog` will have been destroyed long before that time.  Use the debugger to view the call stack at the time of the AV and see who is actually calling `TApplication.GetDialogHandle()` late.

Comment: In any case, when using a smart pointer like `std::auto_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` to manage the lifetime of the `TOpenDialog`, you should set the dialog's `Owner` to `NULL`/`nullptr` instead of `this`: `std::auto_ptr<TOpenDialog> OpenDialog (new TOpenDialog(NULL));`. Although it is perfectly safe to use `this`, it is redundant to do so in this case.

Comment: Builder 10.4 v. 27.0.40680.4203. For nullptr - Undefined symbol 'nullptr'. When I don`t enter TOpenDialog the program is closed normally.

Comment: `nullptr` is only in C++11 and later. The fact that you are using `auto_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr` suggests you are using the "classic" Borland compiler, which does not support C++11. You can use `NULL` instead. In any case, there is nothing in `TOpenDialog` that can cause `TApplication.GetDialogHandle()` to be called after the `TApplication` object has been destroyed. Did you try debugging your app, like I suggested?

Comment: Near as I can see, `TOpenDialog` doesn't use `Application.DialogHandle` at all (`TFindDialog` does, though).

Comment: https://zapodaj.net/a49551d724449.png.html

Comment: I have to use "classic" Borland compiler as there is Excel component in project Excel_2k and using other one there is error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'Excel_2k::XlVAlign' to 'TVariant' (aka 'TVariantT<tagVARIANT, true>')

Comment: that screenshot clearly shows `GetDialogHandle()` being called via a NULL `TApplication` pointer. Why, I can't see. Try enabling "Use Debug DCUs" in the project options and then put a breakpoint on `GetDialogHandle()` itself, maybe you'll get a better call stack to look at.

Comment: There isn such option "DEBUG DCU"

Comment: It is under the [Delphi Compiler Debugging options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Compiling), but it applies to C++Builder, too. Enabling Debug DCUs allows you to step through the VCL/RTL source code with the debugger.

Comment: I can`t find GetDialogHandle() in Vcl.Forms https://zapodaj.net/cd924235db027.png.html

Comment: it is in there. You quoted it verbatim in your question

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this issue. I have project that uses TOpenDialog component.
There was no problem with RAD C++ Builder 10.2 (Tokyo).
But now I get same error after upgrading to RAD C++ Builder 10.4 Update 2 (Sydney).
I don't use dynamic creation TOpenDialog with auto_ptr.
Instead, I just dragged component on my form. So code is very simple:

```
if(!OpenDialog1->Execute())
     return;
```

It's enough to open this dialog, do nothing, press cancel and then close app.
After that I got the same access violation like Jacek had.
So problem is in C++ Builder 10.4

UPDATE:
The problem is not in C++ Builder 10.4 itself.
The error raises when application uses Custom Styles (Themes).
I just disabled Custom Styles in my app and there is no error with OpenDialog.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to disable styling for common dialogs:

```
TStyleManager::SystemHooks = TStyleManager::SystemHooks >> TStyleManager::TSystemHook::shDialogs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround is to set the option ofOldStyleDialog.
The dialog looks old-style but has colors compatible with Widows Themes.

```
OpenDialog1->Options << ofOldStyleDialog;
```